# Is that possible to implement Dynamic RNN with Attention by TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

Is that possible to implement Dynamic RNN with Attention instead of bucketing by TensorFlow ?

If not, how should we implement it?

Many thanks.

Comment: FYI, this post seems to have a thorough treatment on the subject. http://www.wildml.com/2016/08/rnns-in-tensorflow-a-practical-guide-and-undocumented-features/

Comment: This one doesn't give the example of Attention Mechanism, but thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Use [tf.contrib.rnn.AttentionCellWrapper](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/AttentionCellWrapper).

Example:

```
cell_with_attention = tf.contrib.rnn.AttentionCellWrapper(cell, attn_length, ...)
outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell_with_attention, inputs, ...)
```